# Updating Access Data Through Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I think this has a simple answer but I'm driving myself mad trying to Google the answer.
I have an Excel tool which downloads data from an Access Database through VBA. So far, all of that works just fine except for when I try to update the data.

I think the problem is that I am importing data through a QueryTable. I can't seem to get a simpler piece of code to run the following:

1. Create connection to an Access database table
2. Delete all items in the table
3. Run an "INSERT INTO" query for the same table

Here is my code:

```
    Set obj = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & cPath & ";Mode=ReadWrite"), Destination:=Range("W6")).QueryTable
With obj
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array(cRng.Offset(3, 0).Value)
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SaveData = True
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .SourceDataFile = cPath
    .ListObject.DisplayName = cName
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Where,

cPath = Access Database Path

cRng = Excel cell with SELECT query (this works just fine)

cName = Name of table/object

I then run two "with obj"s to update the .CommandText with the DELETE and INSERT INTO queries but that is where Excel says it cannot run the query.

Any ideas? I know the answer can be so simple.

Thank you!

Comment: Please include the full query text in your question. Also, make sure your Excel file doesn't have any non-ascii characters in the cells (Excel tends to add a character to right-align things, an easy check is copy and paste it into the immediate window, and check for unexpected questionmarks).

Comment: They are very simple queries: "SELECT * from tbl_Date", "DELETE * from tbl_Date", and "INSERT INTO tbl_Date VALUES ('7/7/2017')"

Answer (score 0):

The way you're executing queries is valid for queries that return results, but not for action queries, since they don't return anything, and thus Excel can't create a table with their results.

You can execute the queries using ADO (you can leave your select query as-is, and use this for inserts and deletes). You will need to set a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects in Excel (or modify the code to use late binding).

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim adoRS As New ADODB.Recordset
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & cPath & ";Mode=ReadWrite"
adoRS.Open cRng.Offset(3, 0).Value, conn
adoRS.Close
conn.Close
```

Furthermore, your `INSERT` query contains invalid SQL (you haven't specified a column, and assuming you're inserting into a date field, you haven't delimited the date properly (they're `#` delimited), and using the `YYYY/MM/DD` date format is recommended to avoid locale errors).

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Date(MyDateColumn) VALUES (#2017/07/07#)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
Sub RunQueriesInAccess()

    Dim AC As Object
    Set AC = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    Dim strDatabasePath As String
    strDatabasePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Your_Database.accdb"

    With AC
        .OpenCurrentDatabase (strDatabasePath)
        Dim db As Object
        Set db = .CurrentDb
        .DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        .DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query1"
        .DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query2"
        Dim qry As Object
        Set qry = db.QueryDefs("Parameter_Query")
        qry.Parameters(0) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
        qry.Execute

        .DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        .Quit
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```